# Direction of Friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

What is the direction of friction on the wheels of a 4-wheel drive?

What I thought was 
All the 4 wheels have a tendency to rotate such that vehicle goes forward. So friction acts backward.

However, in real life friction must act backward else the car won't stop.

Where am I wrong? Please explain.

Comment: I think you wrote "backwards" twice by mistake. Also, it seems you talk about two different situations. Are you thinking of braking, normal driving or speeding up?

Comment: ... And in real life if some external force (friction) does not act forwards then it won't start moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the car is speeding up , the wheels are rotating and have tendency to go backwards , hence the friction acts in the forward direction , giving a torque and acceleration. Without friction wheels wouldn't be able to rotate just as you wouldn't be able to sit in the car ! When  brakes are applied , they stop start stopping the wheel , the wheel having a tendency to go forwards and hence the friction acts backwards hence stopping the car further. This is all right. But , I had once read when I was in 11th that when a car is accelerating friction acts in  forward direction on 2 wheels (probably ,I had read the front ones) and in backwards direction on the other two. When I read this , it seemed contradictory. I don't know whether it was right or not but certainly , I had read this. If anyone could shed light on this too , it would be better.